# How to split a window title?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, split, title

I'm currently making a program that will list all windows open of a certain application. The application is called "Tibia" and it's a game. When you login to a character, the window title changes to "Tibia - playername".

So let's say I have 3 windows open and are logged in to them. Then I have the following windows open:

```
Tibia - Player 1
Tibia - Player 2
Tibia - Player 3
```

How can I split them and only get the playernames?
This is the code I use to get them and add them into my combobox.

```
        charList.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("Tibia"))
        {
            if (!charList.Items.Contains(p.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                charList.Items.Add(p.MainWindowTitle);
            }
        }
        charList.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I tried to split the "MainWindowTitle" by putting this:

```
charList.Items.Add(p.MainWindowTitle).Split('-');
```

But then it shows up as
`System.String[]` on all items in the combobox

I want the combobox to get filled up with this:

```
Player 1
Player 2
Player 3
```

And not

```
Tibia - Player 1
Tibia - Player 2
Tibia - Player 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read after the `-`:

```
charList.Items.Add(
    p.MainWindowTitle.Substring(p.MainWindowTitle.IndexOf("-") + 2));
```

Comment: That solved it! You sir, are a God! Thank you so much! Never heard about `Substring` before, I will look into it more now, this helped me with a lot of things. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
charList.Items.Add(p.MainWindowTitle.Replace("Tibia - ", "") )
```

Comment: That's also a smart way to do it, I did not think about that! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

split returns an array containing the different groups that the string was split into.  access the player name by using

```
charList.Items[1]
```

you likely also want to trim the string to remove excess spaces

```
charList.Items[1].Trim()
```

Comment: I don't have the .Trim() option when I tried to do that

Answer (score 0):

Would it be simpler to just use substring than split?

```
charList.Items.AddRange(Process.GetProcessesByName("Tibia").ToList()
                        .Distinct().ToList() // Distinct eliminates charlist lookup
                        .ConvertAll<string>(c =>
                        {
                            int dashloc = c.MainWindowTitle.IndexOf("-")
                            return (dashloc > -1)
                                ? c.MainWindowTitle.Substring(dashloc+1).Trim()
                                : c.MainWindowTitle;
                        }));
```